# Coco2d - using CCBitmapFontAtlas

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

i'm trying to create a simple game with  COCO2d but no luck so far...
when i'm trying to create a CCBitmapFontAtlas i get a error saying :

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCBitmapFontAtlas", referenced from:"

and also :

"'CCBitmapFontAtlas' is deprecated "

here is my header file:

```
@interface MainMenuScene : CCLayer
```

{
    CCBitmapFontAtlas* startNewGameLabel;
}

- (id) scene;

@end

and here is my implementation file :

```
#import "MainMenuScene.h"
```

@implementation MainMenuScene

- (id) scene
  {
  CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
  CCLayer* layer = [MainMenuScene node];
  [scene addChild:layer];
  return scene;

}

-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) 
    {
        CCLOG(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self);
        [self setVisible:YES];

```
     startNewGameLabel = [CCBitmapFontAtlas 
                          bitmapFontAtlasWithString:@"New Game" 
                          fntFile:@"bitmapfont.fnt"]; 
                                    //[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"New Game" 
                                    //                 fontName:@"AppleGothic" 
                                    //                 fontSize:48];
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    startNewGameLabel.position = CGPointMake(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    [self addChild:startNewGameLabel];

}
return self;
```

}

- (void) dealloc
  {
  CCLOG(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self);

  [super dealloc];
  }
  @end

I created both .FNT file and .PNG file with heir

Answer (score 7):

You want [CCLabelBMFont](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_label_b_m_font.html) instead of CCBitmapFontAtlas.

```
startNewGameLabel = [CCLabelBMFont
                      labelWithString:@"New Game" 
                      fntFile:@"bitmapfont.fnt"];
```

Comment: should i import something? because the xCode isn't recognize the CCLabelBMFont. and another thing is why the CCBitmapFontAtlas isn't working?? i looked at other codes and everything is same as mine.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of cocos2d? 0.99.5? It works fine for me. CCBitmapFontAtlas is old, in version 0.99.5 you must use CCLabelBMFont.

Comment: but, I got an error, 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid texture for sprite' please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use CCLabelBMFont instead. Will be removed 1.0.1